# Dropbox files on PC display absurd warnings

Tags: dropbox

A new frustration, started recently. When I move or copy any Dropbox file, of any type, to another folder - even another Dropbox folder - I now get the daft message shown below. (Tried to embed image but gave up and used link.)

These are local files, made by me, owned by me. Only happens when the start folder is in Dropbox. I can move or copy files outside Dropbox into a Dropbox folder (or any other folder) as usual, with no silly message.

I've also posted to the Dropbox forum but from experience I'm not optimistic.

[image]

Comment: That is a Windows warning (may be Windows Defender or just Windows). It has found files which may cause issues. It is not a Drop Box warning.

Comment: I didn’t say it was! I

Comment: I interpreted your issue with Dropbox and a report to them to be a Dropbox issue. Did you try Whitelisting in Window Security - WD threats?

Comment: Thanks, currently using iPad, I’ll check that on PC in the morning.

Comment: I have narrowed the issue it down to a single large folder:
C:\Users\terry\Dropbox\3D Printer\

(I've 320 DB folders and use maybe a score frequently. Yet to encounter the msg in any of them apart from that one.)

Here's an annotated screenshot that pretty well sums up where I am:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jty105l1exdpepi/AddedExtension.jpg?raw=1

I've probably read 50 or so threads over the last two days and revisited
many Win 10 settings. Also Internet Options, after seeing advice that
the cause may be down to Intranet settings. But this is a solo use PC with no 'intranet' AFAIK!